# I scared my cat; now she hisses and growls at me. What should I do?

Tags: cats, behavior

I have a stupid habit of running up the stairs. One time I did it while she was at the top, and it was dark so I did not notice her. She started hissing at me and would not move to let me pass through until I went all the way back down and waited a few minutes. Since then, I forgot not to run a few times and ended up scaring her one more time in the same fashion. Now she is afraid of me in any part of the house, and doesn't let me approach. She stopped asking me for food, and only eats when I'm not anywhere near her bowl. This has been going on for about a month, and I don't know if I'm supposed to be doing anything other than letting her be. Is she going to get used to me again eventually?

Comment: IMO you need to have some positive interactions with her. As you can't approach I suggest you get as close as possible and offer treat food. Make yourself as small as possible and move slowly. If she starts to move away, put the food down and back off. I'm sure after month you have an idea of how far away she prefers to be. If she bolts try again tomorrow. You're aiming to hand feed her a few bits. I would stay away from the stairs. Btw I run up stairs too

Comment: Don't try and rebuild her trust near the stairs ^

Comment: Possibly related? https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/17015/made-my-cat-scared-of-me-need-help?rq=1

Comment: Six months down the line now, has it improved?